# Como sobrepor uma imagem do body em cima de uma div?

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma imagem que está dentro do body do css

```
.test-page {
    display: none;
}

html, body {
    margin:0%; height: 99%;
    background-color: #041E43;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color: black;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}

#img{
    background-image: url('../images/img.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.page {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: #041E43;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:0%;
    margin-top:0%;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
}

h1, h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 200%;
}

h2 {
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 200%;
}

p {
    color: blanchedalmond;
    font-size: 250%;
    text-align: center;
}

.button {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20%;    
    margin-left: 15.5%;
}

.footer{
    position: relative;
    top: 92%;
    left: -50%;
    color: white;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.manometer {
    background: white;
    width: 15%;
    height: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 5%;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-left: 12.5%;
    margin-top: 7%;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}

.test-ok {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.test-notok {
    background-color: red;    
}
```

Porém ela fica escondida atras de uma div no index, eu só queria sobrepor ela em cima de tudo, já tentei `position: absolute` mas não deu certo, quebrou o código.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <title>TESTE DE FREIOS</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/manometer.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/button.css">
</head>

<body>

    <button id='b1'>botao sem fio truck</button>
    <button id='b2'>botao sem fio bus</button>
    <button id='b3'>botao inicio/reiniciar</button>
    <button id='b4'>test</button> 

    <div class='container'>
        <div id='content'></div>
    </div>

        <div id='img'></div>

<div class='page' id='page-home'>
    <h1>BEM VINDO, SELECIONE UMA LINHA</h1>
    <button onclick='navigate("truck")' class="button navigation" id='button-truck' >
        TESTE CAMINHÕES
    </button>
    <button onclick='navigate("bus")' class="button navigation" id='button-bus'>
        TESTE ÔNIBUS
    </button>
</div>

    <button onclick='saveToPdf()' >SAVE</button>

    <script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='lib/jspdf.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/saveToPdf.js'></script>
    <script src='js/plc.js'></script>
    <script src='js/pageManager.js'></script>
    <script src='js/sensors.js'></script>

    <div class="footer">&copy; 2017 | Elaborado por Poka Yoke Team | LST Team</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: E porque não criar uma `<div>` com essa imagem e por por cima de tudo?

Comment: Posso estar errado, mas da forma que está sua imagem parece estar sendo carregada 2x, agora creio que seja necessa´rio adicionar o html tmb

Comment: Isac eu fiz isso, porém a imagem não aparece, não sei porque, mesmo caminho , vou postar o html Magic

Comment: o `div img` foi o que criei pra por a imagem, mas no css quando eu edito e coloco o caminho dela, não aparece nada, só aparece no body

Comment: Então coloque também o CSS que carrega a imagem nesse `<div>` na pergunta

Comment: `position: absolute` trabalhar com position requer um certo controle da página (ainda mais quando é absolute), a coisa tem que ser pensada antes de tentar fazer acontecer, por isso sua página desconfigura. Você pode tentar controlar a posição dos elementos utilizando a técnica do `z-index`

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp este link te ajuda a trabalhar com `z-index`, não escrevo uma resposta adequada pois o código que você disponibilizou não ajuda em nada. Está faltando justamente o culpado do problema, a imagem.

Comment: postei todo o css, vou dar uma olhada nesse link Bsalvo

Comment: Fiz um exemplo de z-index para você as vezes pode ajudar https://jsfiddle.net/dL29174x/

Comment: muito bom, isso mesmo que precisava, posta ela aqui que eu marco como respondido , valeu Bsalvo

Answer (score -1):

Se uma das suas `divs` tiver um atributo `position: absolute` ou `position: relative` entre outros, você necessita de usar `z-index` para aumentar a "importância" da `div`. Veja um exemplo do [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).